# Why does Keras layer definitions use nested functions?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I am trying to implement a ResNet model.  I want to use a function to generate the "base" layer (the conv-relu-conv-relu added to the unmodified input) so I could quickly increase the layers programmatically.  However when I passed the layer as a function argument to the function it says it is not a keras tensor.  the first part is my function definition, and the second part is the call, where x_in is the layer object, and y is the output from the residual block.   I use "x" as the previous and next layer name.

```
def ResBlock(x_in, n_filt, l_filt, pool):
    ...
    return y

x = ResBlock(x, 32, 16, 0)
```

After some searching on the google I found this is the proper syntax:

```
def ResBlock(n_filt, l_filt, pool):
    def unit(x_in):
        x = Conv1D(n_filt, l_filt, padding='same')(x_in)
        x = BatchNormalization()(x)
        x = relu(x)
        x = Dropout(0.1)(x)
        x = Conv1D(n_filt, l_filt, padding='same')(x)
        if pool:
            x = MaxPooling1D()(x)
            x_in = MaxPooling1D()(x_in)
        y = keras.layers.add([x, x_in])    
        return y
    return unit

x = ResBlock(32, 16, 0)(x)
```

Can anyone explain why this is the correct way? Specifically, I wonder why we need the nested def for the layer object?

Comment: Without your original code to compare to, this question cannot be answered. You need to be more specific.

Comment: I tried to make the function call clear.  The question I have is why do we need the nested def for the layer object?

Comment: show the code of your version.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying @circuitdesigner5172, I gave you an answer to that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard "style" of Keras is: first define a layer, then apply it. So the code you gave is *not* proper style, which is why you are confused.

The proper style would be:

```
def ResBlock(n_filt, l_filt, pool):
    conv_1 = Conv1D(n_filt, l_filt, padding='same')
    bn = BatchNormalization()
    dropout = Dropout(0.1)
    conv_2 = Conv1D(n_filt, l_filt, padding='same')
    maxpool_1 = MaxPooling1D()
    maxpool_2 = MaxPooling1D()

    def unit(x_in):
        x = conv_1(x_in)
        x = bn(x)
        x = relu(x)
        x = dropout(x)
        x = conv_2(x)
        if pool:
            x = maxpool_1(x)
            x_in = maxpool_2(x_in)
        y = keras.layers.add([x, x_in])    
        return y

    return unit

x = ResBlock(32, 16, 0)(x)
```

The reason we write code like this is to allow re-use of layers. That is, if we call it like this

```
resblock = ResBlock(32, 16, 0)

x = resblock(x)
x = resblock(x)
```

`resblock` would share all parameters between both calls. With the syntax in your example, this would not be possible.